# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to insert `DateTime` variable from ASP.Net C# into an SQL Server database. I get this error for some reason.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; 

string sql2 = @"INSERT INTO registerTable (username,password,email,firstname,gw2user,typeofplay)
                VALUES ('" + user + "','" + pass + "','" + email + "','" + firstname + "','" + gw2user + "','" + type + "','" + date + "')";
```

the date column is a `datetime` date type.

Comment: One should never use unparameterized queries, if there is the possibility to use paramterized queries.

Comment: That certainly is an unexpected error given that it doesn't appear you are inserting anything into a date field. I would expect an error relating to the different number of columns in the field list and the value list.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `date` column in your query. Change it to this to get rid of the error:

```
INSERT INTO registerTable (username,password,email,firstname,gw2user,typeofplay, date) VALUES ('" + user + "','" + pass + "','" + email + "','" + firstname + "','" + gw2user + "','" + type + "','"+date+"')
```

Also, avoid using concatenation and use parametrised queries instead.

Answer (score 2):

don't concatenate parameter values, you better use parameters

```
string sql2 = @"INSERT INTO registerTable (username,password,email,firstname,gw2user,typeofplay, dateColumnName) VALUES (@username,@password,@email,@firstname,@gw2user,@typeofplay, @date)";
```

Read [Working with Parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html)

then you can set date parameter value as below

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
```

do the same for other parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql2 = @"INSERT INTO registerTable (username,password,email,firstname,gw2user,typeofplay, dateColumnName) VALUES (@username,@password,@email,@firstname,@gw2user,@typeofplay, @date)";
```